# How to call a function using script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox which is set up to convert a number into currencies using the following line:

```
$("#price").live('keydown', currenciesOnly).live('blur', function () { $(this).formatCurrency(); });
```

In order for the textbox to convert `81` to `$81.00` the following needs to happen:

1. The HTML field before the textbox has to send the focus to the currency textbox
2. Then the currency textbox has to lose focus to another field.

How can I make it so the currency textbox converts to currency as soon as it has a value instead of losing focus?

Comment: several different mask plugins you could use. Appears from your use of `live()` you are running fairly old version of jQuery so check compatibility with your version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blur event fire only when control lose focus, use keydown event or input event instead.

You probably don’t want interrupt while user is typing, setup a timer do formatCurrentcy when no keydown for a while.